# unable to horizontal draw reference line nvd3 bubble chart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, bubble-chart

I am trying to draw a horizontal line (for reference) in the nvd3 bubble chart. I tried to append a line to svg chart

```
.append('line')
    .attr({
        x1: x(0),
        y1: 10,
        x2: x(3),
        y2: 10
});
```

But am not successful. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dm89/NYJpU/8/) is the fiddle. Note that the `y1` and `y2` values are same (i.e., 10) because I am trying to draw a horizontal line ( `y=10` ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

1. You need to set the `stroke` of your line. Try this:

   ```
   d3.select('#chart svg')
     .append('line')
     .attr({ x1: x(0), y1: 10, x2: x(3), y2: 10 })
     .style("stroke", "#000");
   ```

   This would make a black line in the top left corner of your JSFiddle. However, you are looking to draw the line on your chart where `y=10`. This brings us to point two.
2. Before, you were trying to draw the line at `y1=y2=10` which is just 10 pixels from the top of your SVG. In addition, you were using your own `x` scale. Instead, you need to use the chart's x- and y-axis scales to draw the lines at corresponding point in the chart.  NVD3 has each axis's scale accessible by `chart.axis.scale()` (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392688/how-do-i-access-the-x-and-y-scale-of-the-d3-plot-in-nvd3)), so you can do the following:

   ```
   d3.select('#chart svg')
       .append('line')
       .attr({
           x1: 75 + chart.xAxis.scale()(0),
           y1: 30 + chart.yAxis.scale()(10),
           x2: 75 + chart.xAxis.scale()(3),
           y2: 30 + chart.yAxis.scale()(10)
       })
       .style("stroke", "#000");
   ```

   (Note that there's a 75 pixel left margin and a 30 pixel top margin on the chart, so you need to adjust line's location appropriately.) If you make these changes, you get the image below. See updated JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mdml/sC8zJ/).
   [image]

You can also make sure your line updates with a window resize as follows:

```
nv.utils.windowResize(function(){
    chart.update();
    line.attr({
        x1: 75 + chart.xAxis.scale()(0),
        y1: 30 + chart.yAxis.scale()(10),
        x2: 75 + chart.xAxis.scale()(3),
        y2: 30 + chart.yAxis.scale()(10)
    })

});
```

Comment: Thanks. But why is the line not at y=10? I am unable to understand how this scale x() works.

Comment: @Dinesh: I'm not sure I understand, the line is at `y=10`. And what about `x` do you not understand?

Comment: The line is above the axes. I want to draw a horizontal line at  y(value) = 10 on the y axis. Even with respect to `x`, I am thinking in terms of the axis values on the plot.   As we see horizontal lines on the grid at `y=2,4,8,16 and 32`, I want to draw at `y=10`.

Comment: Thanks. But I tried similar for the x axis- I want like a grid line y=10. but the line starts from before the y axis

Comment: @Dinesh: you can access the `chart`'s x-axis scale in the same way as the y-axis scale. See my updated answer.

Comment: A similar offset is needed in the y axis values.          Also, there seems to be an issue on changing the size of the browser window. The line needs to change its size based on the size of the browser/plot.

Comment: You don't need the margin offsets if you select a deeper element containing just the chart area.  For instance I did .select('svg').select('.nv-stackedarea').